# Create new service builder for liferay with eclipse luna does not work

Tags: eclipse, macos, liferay, liferay-ide

I am trying to create a new service builder for liferay portly project.

If I open the "new Service Builder" dialog, it is not possible for me to click the finish Button.  I tried to do this with the guestbook Portlet example on dev.liferay.com, without success.

Eclipse says that I have to enter a project name.  However, it is not possible to enter something at Plugin project.  I don't know why; perhaps this is a bug?

I did this several times and it worked, but now I've tried this with a new setup.  Perhaps this is the reason.

Setup:
Mac OSX 10.10.4
eclipse Luna 4.4.2
installed Plugins:

- Liferay
- Git
- Maven

Liferay 6.2

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You're using Liferay IDE, right? (I assume that's what you mean when you say you have Liferay installed as a plugin.)

Maybe with your new setup, Eclipse doesn't recognize your guestbook project as a valid Liferay Plugin project. When you click New -> Liferay Service Builder, you have to select a Liferay Plugin project within which to create the Service Builder stuff. Since you can't select anything at the Plugin project selector, I'd guess that Eclipse doesn't recognize any of your projects as valid Liferay Plugin projects.

Note that if you click New -> Liferay Plugin Project, you have to specify a Liferay Plugins SDK and a Liferay runtime. You need to have both of these configured in your new environment.

For Plugins SDK, go to Eclipse's Preferences Window then Liferay -> Installed Plugin SDKs. Add the Plugins SDK that contains your guestbook project and re-import your guestbook project from this SDK. Then check if the Service Builder wizard lets you select your project via the selector.